# Using local variables in SQL xml attribute value

Tags: sql-server, xml, variables, local

I have re-purposed some code to parse a comma delimited string in a single field into separate fields.
I now want to incorporate loops to number the new fields using local variables (I'm thinking this is the best method) as well as using them in the singleton value [1] etc.

[1] would be [WT1], [2] would be [SA1], [3]=[WT2], [4]=[SA2], etc

The number of loops needs to be set by a local variable and will change, so I cant just make a finite number of new fields for output.

I have been able to use local variables to replace 'Attribute' in the NewXml.value string, but cant manage the syntax for the singleton value.

I suppose the the variable i needs to be converted to a string.
I also want to incorporate it in the loop for the output new field names eg. WT1, SA1, WT2, SA2, etc.

I have commented out the looping lines of code, as well as the first field (WT1) in the SELECT which I cant get to work which is the same as the line for the existing WT1.

I hope I have explained myself clearly enough for a solution.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
ProductId INT,
ProductName VARCHAR(25),
SupplierId INT,
Descr VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1,'Product1',1,'A1,10in,30in,2lbs');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (2,'Product2',2,'T6,15in,30in,');
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (3,'Product3',1,'A2,1in,,0.5lbs');


declare @i  int;
set @i=1;

declare @prodatt VARCHAR(25);
set @prodatt ='Attribute';
--while @i < 8
--begin
SELECT 
--  NewXML.value('(/Product[1]/Attribute[*[local-name() = sql:variable("@i")])]','varchar(25)') AS [WT1],
    NewXML.value('(/Product[1]/*[local-name() = sql:variable("@prodatt")])[2]','varchar(25)') AS [SA1],

    NewXML.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[1]','varchar(25)') AS [WT1],
--  NewXML.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[2]','varchar(25)') AS [SA1],
    NewXML.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[3]','varchar(25)') AS [WT2],
    NewXML.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[4]','varchar(25)') AS [SA2],
    [ProductID],
    [SupplierId]
FROM @t t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT XMLEncoded=(SELECT Descr AS [*] FROM @t t2 WHERE t1.ProductId = t2.[ProductId] FOR XML PATH(''))) EncodeXML
CROSS APPLY (SELECT NewXML=CAST('<Product><Attribute>'+REPLACE(XMLEncoded,',','</Attribute><Attribute>')+'</Attribute></Product>' AS XML)) CastXML
```

Comment: Paula, what is your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is much cleaner implementation. If you want to make it absolutely dynamic, you would need to use dynamic SQL.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductName VARCHAR(25),
    SupplierId INT,
    Descr VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
(1,'Product1',1,'A1,10in,30in,2lbs')
, (2,'Product2',2,'T6,15in,30in,')
, (3,'Product3',1,'A2,1in,,0.5lbs');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

-- Method #1, via XML
;WITH rs AS
(
   SELECT ProductID, Descr
      , TRY_CAST(N'<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
         REPLACE(Descr, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') +
            ']]></r></root>' AS XML) AS xmldata
   FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ProductID, Descr
   , xmldata.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS WT1
   , xmldata.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS SA1
   , xmldata.value('(/root/r[3]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS WT2
   , xmldata.value('(/root/r[4]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS SA2
   , xmldata.value('(/root/r[5]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS WT3
   , xmldata.value('(/root/r[6]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS SA3
FROM rs;
```

> Output

```
+-----------+-------------------+-----+------+------+--------+------+------+
| ProductID |       Descr       | WT1 | SA1  | WT2  |  SA2   | WT3  | SA3  |
+-----------+-------------------+-----+------+------+--------+------+------+
|         1 | A1,10in,30in,2lbs | A1  | 10in | 30in | 2lbs   | NULL | NULL |
|         2 | T6,15in,30in,     | T6  | 15in | 30in | NULL   | NULL | NULL |
|         3 | A2,1in,,0.5lbs    | A2  | 1in  | NULL | 0.5lbs | NULL | NULL |
+-----------+-------------------+-----+------+------+--------+------+------+
```

Comment: thanks.  I'll try to unpack the code.  I'm not totally familiar with XML so I need to work out some of your code and I know I'm not writing the most efficient code for my purpose, so this is very helpful.  However, it doesn't seem to set the local variable I need to loop and change the WT/SA names and singleton values. Is that dynamic sql?

Comment: @Paula, What I shared with you is not a dynamic SQL. IMHO, you don't need a dynamic SQL. If you need to shred a comma separated string value in a single column with more tokens, just add 2 more lines to the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Yes, but this code is to be share with other users and the variable can change each year depending on an imported file.  So I would like to make it all dynamic, so that the user doesn't need to touch it.  

Alternatively, I guess I could just make the SELECT with as many lines as I think will ever be needed.

Comment: "...I could just make the SELECT with as many lines as I think will ever be needed..." That was exactly my point. IMHO, it is not worth it to use a dynamic SQL.